# using apache http server on HP-UX OS.we are facing an issue where httpd count is not going down

Tags: apache, hp-ux

httpd count taken with ps -ef|grep httpd|wc -l is very HIGH 
Normally it should be within 100-150 but it now going high to even 2000
when we increased Maxclients value to 2000.

Whatever be the value of Maxclients,when issue occurs httpd count goes to extreme value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what the webserver is doing, look at mod_status and backtraces of the httpd processes.   Anything that slows down the response will eventually cause this symptom.